# I cannot get Boolean operations work on latest Delphi

Tags: delphi

I am beginning to think I am losing my mind.  I have Delphi 10.4.2 with latest patch.
I cannot get this Boolean to work

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var j,k, m: integer;
begin
  j := 1; m := 14;
  k := j And m;
end;
```

I am happy to be proved wrong but in my books 1 logical and 14 should result in 1 but it is reporting as 0.

Comment: No, I am pretty sure `14` is an *even* number. Hence, its LSB is `0`, so if you `and` it with `1`, you get `0`. Perhaps you are not aware of [bitwise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND) boolean operators?

Comment: Just realised I should have  inverted it.  I am losing my mind sorry to have troubled you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this context, you are not using `And` as a Boolean operator, as the arguments are not Booleans.

Instead, it's being used as a bitwise operator.

1 is, well, 1, or 00000001 in binary.

14 is $0e, or 00001110 in binary.

When you do a bitwis `and` of $0e and $1, you will get 0 - which is correct.

Answer (score 1):

`And` in this case is a bitwise operator.

14 is 1110 in binary.

1 is 0001 in binary.

```
1110 & 0001 = 0
```